# How to check if a user has voted before 24hrs rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to check whether the user has voted before 24 hours if yes I need to allow him to vote

```
if current_user.vote = true
  if @vote.updated_at > Time.now - 24.hours          
    @vote.save          
  end
end
```

but I am getting error as
**undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass**
So how can I fix this?

Comment: `@vote.updated_at` is nil.

Comment: Can you show `Vote` model and `User` model, what is relation, and so on. Give some more information

Comment: @Nermin http://pastie.org/10407006

Comment: Update question with your complete action.

Comment: @Pavan Can I define like this in if? 'if vote.updated_at > Time.now - 24.hours'

Comment: @Dipak http://pastie.org/10407014 check this please, and my model  pastie.org/10407006

Comment: Use this code http://pastie.org/10407027

Comment: @Dipak again i am getting the same error after pasting your code 'undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass' this occurs because in update_at column there is no value as current user is voting 1st time.

Comment: Try create vote object after all condition pass like this http://pastie.org/10407124

Comment: Is this working for you?

Comment: @Dipak 'if current_user.votes.last.updated_at > Time.now - 24.hours' is not working, it simply saving the data. can you please give me the solution for it

Comment: Your symbol is wrong it should be less than. `current_user.votes.last.updated_at > Time.now - 24.hours` should be `current_user.votes.last.updated_at < Time.now - 24.hours` Then it will give you right output

Comment: @Dipak yep, you are right ;-) ashamed of me,wasting couple of hours for this silly mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question and your code block following is the problem with your code

```
if current_user.vote = true ## This always return true so you should have `current_user.votes.present?`
  if @vote.updated_at > Time.now - 24.hours ## @vote object is blank instaed it should be `current_user.votes.last.updated_at < Time.now - 24.hours`
    @vote.save          
  end
end
```

So try change like this :

```
if current_user.votes.present?
  if current_user.votes.last.updated_at < Time.now - 24.hours
    @vote.save          
  end
end
```

considering @vote is your new object